# Display pop up with dynamic data on click from button Django template

Tags: django, popup

I have a project where i am passing doctionary data from view to template and creating buttons inside the html page from template. now if user clicks on button it should show a pop up window ( bootstap implemented modal ) and show some more info regarding clicked items.
i already have object containing more information corresponding to button.

how can i acheive this ?

Answer (score 2):

I got into exactly the same situation as you are having now with my project 2 months ago. Below is how I did it. My context was that when user clicks the Share button, the modal will show up with the name of the note that they want to share with other users <--- This is the dynamic data part you are looking for.

In my `template.html` there is a Share button like below:

```
<a
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    class="open-share-note-modal"
    data-url="{% url 'write:get-note-to-share' note_id %}"
>
    Share
</a>
```

Note the `data-url="{% url 'write:get-note-to-share' note_id %}"`. It does the magic. You will also want to read more about `data-url` and what it does exactly.

The `{% url 'write:get-note-to-share' note_id %}` will link to this function in my `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def get_note_to_share(request, pk=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=pk)
    context = {'note': instance}
    return render(request, 'write/_modal_share_note.html', context)
```

The `'write/_modal_share_note.html'` is the modal with dynamic data I want to inject into.

Then finally, in my `template.html` again:

Create a `<div>`wrapper like this:

`<div id="share-note-modal-wrapper"></div>`

Then a bit JavaScript to inject the modal into the wrapper:

```
        var shareNoteModalDiv = $("#share-note-modal-wrapper");
        $(".open-share-note-modal").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    shareNoteModalDiv.html(data);
                    $("#share-note").modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
```

It worked with me. Let me know if I have made it clear.